# Get the right data from date and history

Tags: mysql

I have a database which includes tables like these:

[image]

My goal is to get the information from `Place` or `PlaceUpdateHistory` depends on the `control_date` field. In case of `PlaceUpdateHistory`, I want the good version corresponding to `control_date`. In other words, I want something like that:

```
IF control_date > last update_date
THEN SELECT * FROM Place
ELSE SELECT * FROM PlaceUpdateHistory WHERE first of control_date > update_date
```

I prefer a solution in full SQL.

Here a execution example:
[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired result

Comment: Not sure if i'v caught your point correctly but i think you can simply solve this by changing your ER Diagram, This entity relationship set does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be a relationship between update table and control table, and because there is none here, then the logic become a little bit complicated.

Based on your requirements you can create another table which holds:

- The id of PlaceHistoryUpdate element
- The id of Control element which associated with that update record.

And another thing is that you don't need an entity like Place, This makes your job easier if you just hold all your place records in the PlaceUpdateRecords, This is logically correct, too.

Then you just have PlaceUpdateRecords, Control and UpdateRecord_Control entities. This way the query become much more easier and still is logically correct, too.

Comment: you're right, my operation was too complicated. I have just changed my trigger who fill PlaceUpdateHistory to fill with new values. As well, i just have to query the table PlaceUpdateHistory to go. Thanks for giving me another point of view.

Comment: Your welcome, And if you decided to have the table UpdateRecord_Control, There is a further optimization and that is if you have a one-to-one relationship(Cardinality) between PlaceUpdateHistory and Control tables, then there is no need of an individual table to hold relation between these two. instead hold the corresponding control id in each row of PlaceUpdateHistory. This way redundancy will be reduced.